# Permute association key and generate a sparse array

Tags: associations, sparse-arrays

Imagine having an `Association`

```
Av = <|{1, 4, 2, 3} -> a, {2, 4, 2, 4} -> b|>
```

It can be much longer. I am searching for an idiomatic and transparent way to construct a `SparseArray` out of it: `Sv=buildSA[Av]` The caveat is that each value corresponds to 8 possible permutation of indices. In particular, given the entry `{i,j,k,l}->v`, the sparse array should also contain

```
{i,j,k,l}->v
{l,j,k,i}->v
{l,k,j,i}->v
{i,k,j,l}->v
{j,i,l,k}->v
{k,i,l,j}->v
{k,l,i,j}->v
{j,l,i,k}->v
```

These symmetry properties come from the underlying definition

`Sv[[i,j,k,l]]=Integrate[f[i][x] f[j][y] f[k][y] f[l][x] v[x,y],{x,...},{y,...}]`

and the fact that `v[x,y]==v[y,x]`.

I have a way to do that,

```
buildSA[a_] := Module[{b, ki, vi},
  b = <||>;
  Do[
   vi = a[ki];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{1, 2, 3, 4}]] -> vi];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{4, 2, 3, 1}]] -> vi];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{4, 3, 2, 1}]] -> vi];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{1, 3, 2, 4}]] -> vi];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{2, 1, 4, 3}]] -> vi];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{3, 1, 4, 2}]] -> vi];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{3, 4, 1, 2}]] -> vi];
   AssociateTo[b, ki[[{2, 4, 1, 3}]] -> vi];
   ,
   {ki, Keys[a]}];
  SparseArray[b // Normal]
  ]
```

but it looks very artificial. What would be the natural way to do it?

Comment: Why specifically these 8 permutations?

Comment: @Szabolcs The elements of the sparse array I am constructing are essentially integrals of the product of 4 functions. The permutation symmetry comes from the symmetry of integrals with respect to the permutation of functions.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have updated the post with the explanation of the reason for symmetries and my own messy implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe with `SymmetrizedArray`?

```
size = 4;
rank = 4;
Av = <|{1, 4, 2, 3} -> a, {2, 4, 2, 4} -> b|>;
symmetries = {
   {{4, 2, 3, 1}, 1},
   {{4, 3, 2, 1}, 1},
   {{1, 3, 2, 4}, 1},
   {{2, 1, 4, 3}, 1},
   {{3, 1, 4, 2}, 1},
   {{3, 4, 1, 2}, 1},
   {{2, 4, 1, 3}, 1}
   };
A = SparseArray[
  SymmetrizedArray[Normal[Av], ConstantArray[n, rank], symmetries]
  ]
```

In the list `symmetries`, each entry is a pair `{p,s}` of a permutation `p` that can be applied and a sign `s` (`1`, `-1`) that tells us whether the array is meant to be symmetric (`s = 1` means symmetric, `s = -1` means antisymmetric).

In fact, it suffices to provide only a set of generators of the symmetry group. For example,

```
symmetries = {
   {{4, 2, 3, 1}, 1},
   {{1, 3, 2, 4}, 1},
   {{2, 4, 1, 3}, 1}
   };
```

would lead to the same result

Comment: Very nice! Especially appealing is the possibility to only provide a list of generators.

Comment: Thank you very much!   =)

Answer (score 5):

```
pg = PermutationGroup[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 
     3, 2, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {2, 4, 1, 3}}];

ClearAll[sAbuild]
sAbuild = SparseArray[KeyValueMap[Alternatives @@ 
         GroupOrbits[pg, {#}, Permute][[1]] -> #2 &]@#, #2] &;

dims = {4, 4, 4, 4};

sAbuild[Av, dims]
```

[image]

Based on Henrik's answer, we can use a smaller set of generators to get the same result:

```
pg = PermutationGroup @ {{4, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 1, 3}};
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking in this direction, but could not figure it out the `KeyValueMap` with `Alternatives` construction. I guess the group should be possible to build from the constructors somehow.